# textarea adding spaces for every \n

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, textarea, newline

Here is the value of a field:

```
"This is my special statement.\nLine 2.\nLine 3."
```

In my textarea, it is displaying like this:

```
This is my special statement.
            Line 2.
            Line 3.
```

My `erb` code for this textarea is:

```
<%= text_area :user, :custom_statement, :class => "field" %>
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: You should escape the "\n" character.

Answer (score 0):

Are you centering the content of your textarea maybe? Check the CSS for .field .

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as:

```
"Your text".gsub("\n","\r")
```